# Mongoose - Update each subdocument in array (node.js)

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I re-read all of Google, but couldn't find the right answer. I really hope for your help!

Can I update all the subdocuments in items array? Here is example:

```
const newName = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']; 

{
_id: ObjectId('1')
items: [
    {
        _id: ObjectId('11'),
        name: ''
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('12')
        name: ''
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('13')
        name: ''
    }
]
}
```

What i tried to do:

```
.update({ _id: ObjectId('1') }, {$set: { 'items.$.name': newName }},false,true);
```

But it's working only when `newName` is a String and only to the first object in array. `$[]` do the same with one exception, the same `String` value is set in each object. With array  `newName` it's not working at all.

How can I solve this problem? Search every time by the object `_id` is not an option.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, your current update will only update the first element in the array with the positional operator ($), and all elements to the same value with the 'all positional operator' ($[]). Multiple edits to arrays/subdocs are a bit tricky with mongoose, I've found.

I think there are a couple of ways you could go about this though. A perhaps naive (and not recommended) approach might be to find() the document to be updated, then work on the document object, looping over the array to be updated to update each object (using a standard js array iterator to match the indexes with the update array values), before calling a save() on the main document. However, I do believe this may run the risk of someone else trying to update the document during the window of your retrieval, update and write back, as it's not atomic.

A second, safer option would be to set up a [Model.bulkWrite()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite), which would allow you to update the document in place with multiple edits using an array of updateOne 'ops'. So you'd find() the array/subdoc you wish to update, create your array of updateOne commands in js, mapping over the subdoc until you've covered all the arrays you need to update, then call the bulkWrite() command to update everything in one shot.

Hope this points you in the right direction. Good luck!